# ¿Clase Point acumula Memoria Ram con cada New C#?

Tags: c#, hilos

tengo un problema.
Estoy realizando un juego sencilo el que consiste mover un picturebox cada vez que presiono una tecla y para mover el PictureBox utilizo:

```
pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X+10, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
```

Y me he dado cuenta que mientras se mueve mi pictureBox por el form la aplicacion consume mas y mas memoria ram,inmagino que es porque se realiza muchos New Point.
Por favor alguien me ayuda a resolver este problema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé hasta que punto el incremento de memoria se deba a la creación de los puntos, pero se me ocurre que puedes establecer una variable de tipo Point, modificarla y asignársela al PictureBox cada vez que pulses una tecla. Algo así:

```
// Esto iría a nivel de clase...
Point Punto = new Point(xInicial, yInicial);

// Al pulsar una tecla iría esto...
Punto.X += 10;
pictureBox1.Location = Punto;
```

De esta manera reutilizarías el objeto Punto en cada movimiento sin generar cada vez un punto nuevo, aunque debido a que Point es una estructura y creo que es inmutable, el problema de la memoria podría seguir igual, ya que se genera un nuevo objeto Point al modificar un valor del mismo.

Un saludo.